# Multiple inheritance in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, multiple-inheritance

Can multiple inheritance be mapped in hibernate ORM? 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Teneo/Hibernate/ModelRelational/Inheritance_Mapping says hibernate itself does not support multiple inheritance so is there a way to implement multiple inheritance or no?(Note its multiple inheritance not multilevel inheritance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple inheritance in java is only possible via interfaces, not objects. Because Hibernate is ORM framework it doesn't map interfaces, but map classes to database tables. So, there's not multiple inheritance in Hibernate.